# Random URL like megaupload

Tags: php, mysql

I need to sell pictures. I need to create a  megaupload like system to create ramdom url, like this: "http://download.server.com/7fdfug87g89f7g98fd7g/image.jpg" associated with the session and IP address.

I'm using PHP, Apache or Nginx.

How can I achieve this?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) in the `.htaccess` file to redirect requests matching some patterns you define to a php file, 'index.php' perhaps.

This way you can pass the requested string as a URL parameter to the page. And then in the script you can use the parameter to find and return the related image.

It's called 'URL rewriting', and is the way how those sites with meaningful URLs work, just like the URLs of stackoverflow.

For the uniqueness; rather than bare hash codes, you'll probably need to keep a DB to map the codes with files. So they may be totally random codes in any length you wish, and never collide, as during the assignment you will create a new random one if the one you just created collides with another one already in the DB. And you can add clear IP and session info to the DB record. This also removes the need of some heavy calculations for hashing algorithms.

Comment: I would still want to associate that hash string with a user id so that only a logged in user has access to it, otherwise it can be passed on to others. If that's not desirable, I'd set an expiry timestamp so it's only usable for 48 or so.

Comment: @niggles sure, some relation with the user ID is a need in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Something like md5 would be within reason.

```
$my_seed = "something random here";
$path = md5($my_seed . $_SESSION['something'] . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

echo "http://download.server.com/" . $path . "/" . $file;
```

That should give you a pretty unique path to put files in that would be rare to collide.  You should still check if the previous hash'd path exists though.

Comment: Good. But, I need the images in the same directory. And create URL on the fly to my users.

Comment: $path is just for the directory.... use mkdir($path) to make the directory, and put all the images in the directory.... then all the files will be "http://download.server.com/" . $path . "/" . $filename1, "http://download.server.com/" . $path . "/" . $filename2, etc

Comment: He needs unique strings, this will not create an unique string.

Comment: His post says 'Associated with session and ip address'.  This will create a unique path, for each variance of 'session variable' and 'ip address'.  He didn't say he just wanted a random string, its not random if its seeded by session and ip

Answer (score 0):

Use some of the popular hash functions out there, such as MD5. There should be a PHP module capable of that.

Comment: Sure. There's more work to do. But MD5 or other hash functions give a good starting point. The exact date and time of the upload, together with the MD5 over the entire file might be encoded in a one-to-one fashion towards the final filename. The hashing is done to have something that cannot easily be converted back to the original filename.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a hashing function like sha1 or md5 to generate a pseudorandom string of hexadecimal digits based on the current time plus some other bit of data unique to whatever the URL is about.